# spring amqp setConfirmCallback problems

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I configure the rabbitTemplate like below:

```java
@Autowired
public Sender(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    //消息是否到达交换机的回调
    rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
        if (!ack) {
            log.info("sender not send message to the right exchange" + " correlationData=" + correlationData + " ack=" + ack + " cause" + cause);
        } else {
            log.info("sender send message to the right exchange" + " correlationData=" + correlationData + " ack=" + ack + " cause" + cause);
        }
    });
    //消息是否到达正确的消息队列，如果没有会把消息返回
    rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, tmpExchange, tmpRoutingKey) -> {
        log.info("Sender send message failed: " + message + " " + replyCode + " " + replyText + " " + tmpExchange + " " + tmpRoutingKey);
        //try to resend msg
    });

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(500);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(10.0);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(10000);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    rabbitTemplate.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;

}
```

and the send method

```java
  public void send() {
        System.out.println("sender is sending message");
        String uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String uuid3 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println("UUID="+uuid1+"---"+uuid2+"---"+uuid3);
        // the right excharge name and routing key 
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitMQConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, "aaa.orange.bbb", "hello,world1 2", new CorrelationData(uuid1));
         // wrong exchage name 
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("测试交换机名", "aaa.orange.ccc", "测试错误的交换机名", new CorrelationData(uuid2));
        // wrong excharge name  
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("测试交换机名", "1111111", "测试错误的队列名", new CorrelationData(uuid3));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my question is when i only code

```java
 rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitMQConfig.EXCHANGE_NAME, "aaa.orange.bbb", "hello,world1 2", new CorrelationData(uuid1));
```

comment two lines

```java
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("测试交换机名", "aaa.orange.ccc", "测试错误的交换机名", new CorrelationData(uuid2));
// wrong excharge name  
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("测试交换机名", "1111111", "测试错误的队列名", new CorrelationData(uuid3));
```

the `confirmCallback` log is `"sender send message to the right exchange"`

But if I send three message at once, the `confirmCallback` logs are 
three `"sender not send message to the right exchange"` log and I check the queue, the right message is sending to the queue, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should be sure that there is a proper binding on the Broker via `测试交换机名` and `aaa.orange.ccc` routing key. The same is applied for the `"测试交换机名", "1111111"` pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear; if you mean you are sending to a non-existent exchange - that is considered fatal for the channel so any pending confirms will be lost.

Since Spring AMQP caches channels for reuse, downstream operations can cause the channel to be closed and the confirm lost.

For example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48518319Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48518319Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, cause) -> {
                System.out.println(correlation + ":" + ack + " " + (cause == null ? "" : cause));
                ((MyCorrelationData) correlation).getLatch().countDown();
            });
            MyCorrelationData foo = new MyCorrelationData("foo");
            MyCorrelationData bar = new MyCorrelationData("bar");
            MyCorrelationData baz = new MyCorrelationData("baz");
            template.convertAndSend("output", "output.foo", "foo", foo);
            template.convertAndSend("output", "output.foo", "foo", bar);
            template.convertAndSend("output", "output.foo", "foo", baz);
            if (!foo.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Foo failed");
            }
            if (!bar.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Bar failed");
            }
            if (!baz.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Baz failed");
            }
            System.out.println("All good");
        };
    }

    public static class MyCorrelationData extends CorrelationData {

        private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public MyCorrelationData(String id) {
            super(id);
        }

        protected CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return this.latch;
        }

        protected void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

    }

}
```

works well

```java
CorrelationData [id=foo]:true 
CorrelationData [id=bar]:true 
CorrelationData [id=baz]:true
```

All good, but if I change it to

```java
template.convertAndSend("output", "output.foo", "foo", foo);
template.convertAndSend("noutput", "output.foo", "foo", bar);
template.convertAndSend("noutput", "output.foo", "foo", baz);
```

we get

```java
CorrelationData [id=foo]:false channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'noutput' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
CorrelationData [id=bar]:false channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'noutput' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
CorrelationData [id=baz]:false channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'noutput' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

To avoid reusing the channel until the ack is received, you can use the template's `invoke` method; this prevents the channel from being reused for the bad sends:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So48518319Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So48518319Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            template.setConfirmCallback((correlation, ack, cause) -> {
                System.out.println(correlation + ":" + ack + " " + (cause == null ? "" : cause));
                MyCorrelationData myCorrelation = (MyCorrelationData) correlation;
                myCorrelation.getLatch().countDown();
                myCorrelation.setAck(ack);
            });
            MyCorrelationData foo = new MyCorrelationData("foo");
            MyCorrelationData bar = new MyCorrelationData("bar");
            MyCorrelationData baz = new MyCorrelationData("baz");
            boolean result1 = template.invoke(t -> {
                t.convertAndSend("output", "output.foo", "foo", foo);
                try {
                    if (!foo.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Foo failed");
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return foo.isAck();
            });
            boolean result2 = template.invoke(t -> {
                t.convertAndSend("noutput", "output.foo", "bar", bar);
                try {
                    if (!bar.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Bar failed");
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return bar.isAck();
            });
            boolean result3 = template.invoke(t -> {
                t.convertAndSend("noutput", "output.foo", "baz", baz);
                try {
                    if (!baz.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("Baz failed");
                    }
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return baz.isAck();
            });
            System.out.println("All done: " + result1 + "," + result2 + "," + result3);
        };
    }

    public static class MyCorrelationData extends CorrelationData {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        private volatile boolean ack;

        public MyCorrelationData(String id) {
            super(id);
        }

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return this.latch;
        }

        public boolean isAck() {
            return this.ack;
        }

        public void setAck(boolean ack) {
            this.ack = ack;
        }

    }

}
```

with

```java
CorrelationData [id=foo]:true 
CorrelationData [id=bar]:false channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'noutput' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
CorrelationData [id=baz]:false channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'noutput' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

All done: `true, false, false`

But that defeats the benefit of using publisher confirms, unless you do the sends on separate threads.

Bottom line is "don't send messages to non-existent exchanges if you are using confirms".

Comment: thanks a lot ,yes, i mean  sending message  to a non-existent exchange .Now I know  that is considered fatal for the channel so any pending confirms will be lost. I still have one question  
what is the use of  "cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns() "

Comment: when I setPublisherReturns(false)
and rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true), I also can get return by ReturnCallback if the routingkey is wrong 
when I cachingConnectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true)
and do not setMandatory(true), and i can  not get return by ReturnCallback if the routingkey is wrong. it seems no working? or it has other use

Comment: You should really ask another question rather than piggy-backing on this one. Confirms and returns are related in terms of how they are implemented by the framework. If you enable one, they are both enabled at the channel level. We should probably have used a single flag on the connection factory. You must set `mandatory` to `true` for returns.

Comment: Actually, we need two flags because there is a small behavior difference when we close a channel if returns are enabled but not confirms.